# emacs daemon server doesn't start on os x startup

Tags: macos, emacs

I wrote an "emacsinit" file like

```
/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/24.1/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs --daemon
```

and drag the file "emacsinit" into the "Login Items".
But it doesn't seem to work. The server doesn't start after system start.
How can I deal with it?

Answer (score 3):

The Login Items scheme likely expects that the launched apps are full app bundles, not just individual shell scripts.

A tool called [Platypus](http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus/) can be used to wrap your shell script up as a full application.

Another option is to create an OS X per-user launchd item for Emacs, which is easy if you use an app called [Lingon](http://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/index.html). (Older Lingon versions were free, and will also do the trick.)

For what it's worth, I get all the same advantages with less work by starting the regular Emacs app and then activating the server with the following code:

```
(require 'server)
(unless (server-running-p)
  (server-start))
```

After that, I can create new text and graphical frames freely using `emacsclient`.